# Does ChiRunning reduce number of injuries experienced while running?

Tags: medical-science, sport

[Chi Running](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChiRunning) style of running [is said](http://running.competitor.com/2009/05/training/can-running-technique-be-taught_298) to significantly reduce number of injuries experienced while running:

> The top-selling running book of the last several years is Chi Running, by Danny Dreyer, which teaches a quasi-yoga-based style of running that is purported to reduce injury risk.

Chi Running supporters [published results of surveys](http://www.chirunning.com/about/for-the-press/) between Chi Runners, which contain claims like:

> 92 % feel Chi Running / Chi Walking has played a role in preventing running/walking injuires

Does Chi Running really reduce the number of injuries caused by (or experienced during) running?

Comment: This article might help in composing an answer: http://www.sportsscientists.com/2007/10/pose-running-reduces-running-economythe.html

Comment: Chi running technique (other than leaning forward) sounds similar to older running techniques of landing on the forefoot, and keeping bent knees advocated by Olympic runner Gordon Pirie: http://www.scribd.com/doc/13695/Gordon-Piries-Running-Fast-and-Injury-Free I think the real issue is that the recently developed style of landing on your heels (which only came about after trainers were invented) causes injuries.

Answer (score -3):

Chi running, which focuses on running form can indeed reduce injuries by virtue of the fact that most running injuries are results of poor running form, too much too soon or overuse.

The idea of making contact with the ground with the joints bent so as to reduce the impact on the joints and to leverage the soft tissue of the legs to both absorb the impact as well as propel the body forward can reduce injuries, it is easily understandable when considering that soft tissue (ligaments,tendons and muscle) heals and strengthens itself faster because of the higher blood flow when compared to the low to inexistent blood flow to various parts of hard tissue(bone) and joints.
Avoiding over-striding by making contact with the ground right below the center of gravity is also one of the ideas that helps.

This combined with minimalist to barefoot footwear can strengthen the bones, tendons, ligaments and muscles of the feet, lower legs, upper legs, hips etc.

Care should be taken however, not to push too hard, too soon as strengthening takes time and regardless of the type of running style, overuse can cause injuries.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims. This currently reads as an advert repeating the claims, rather than an answer providing empirical evidence.

Comment: This is just a repetition of the claim.